# Is it possible to build .NET 1.1 apps with VS.NET 2008?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008

I'm going to maintain an existing .NET 1.1 app for my client.  VS.NET 2008 seems not to be able to build .NET 1.1 projects out-of-the-box but I don't want to install VS.NET 2003 just for this particular project.  Is it possible to use VS.NET 2008 for .NET 1.1 development?  How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Luke H's blog, no:

> No - Visual Studio 2008 will not support targeting .Net Framework 1.1.  This is something we really wanted to be able to support - since we know there are a lot of .NET developers working on .NET 1.1 applications.  However, it would have been significantly more difficult to go back and support .NET 1.1 which was a substantially different runtime.
>
> Thus, to fit in this release, the decision ended up being either to not support multitargeting at all - or to support only targeting .NET2.0 and greater.  Because we really wanted Visual Studio 2008 to be a great tool for at least both .NET 3.0 and .NET 3.5 - we decided to put in the most multitargeting support we could fit in this release.

http://blogs.msdn.com/lukeh/archive/2007/06/29/net-framework-multitargeting-in-visual-studio-2008-aka-orcas.aspx#3627411

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, quick answer is "no".  I strongly suggest you install VS.Net 2003 as it happily co-exists with 2008 (We do that on all our machines here).

Even if you got it to build in 2008 from the command line, you'll still miss all the IntelliSense and wizards.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to target 1.1, just ensure you do not use any 2.0 features such as generics and a load of other good stuff, and then compile using the csc.exe or vbc.exe compiler in the 1.1 directory.

Answer (score 0):

I [posted a similar question recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477266/is-there-a-relatively-painless-upgrade-path-from-asp-net-1-1-to-3-5) about upgrading an ASP.NET 1.1 project to 3.5, and ended up deciding to upgrade the project to VS 2008, just using an import wizard.  The process was surprisingly simple; in my case, with a relatively straightforward Web project consisting of a few dozen Web forms, the process took only a couple of minutes, and I was relieved not to have encountered a single exception in testing afterward.

Answer (score 0):

If your code matches certain requirements,

1. No partial,
2. No generics,
3. ......

You may try out MSBee here

http://www.codeplex.com/MSBee

It would be very complicated while installing VS2003 is a much easier option.